# quantikz/tikz slice text placement

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

For the slice element of quantikz, I would like to place the text at the bottom, for example I can do this with the `A1` and `B1` text as

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{a}
    & \gate[2, style={fill=blue!20, rounded corners}]{A} \slice[style=blue, label style={yshift=-9.8em}]{A1}
    & 
    &
    & \meter[3, style={fill=red!25, rounded corners}]{X} \\
    \lstick{b}
    &
    & \gate[style={fill=green!25, rounded corners}]{S} 
    & \gate[2, style={fill=orange!20, rounded corners}]{B} \slice[label style={yshift=-9.8em}]{B1} 
    &\\
    \lstick{c}
    &
    & 
    & 
    &
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

with `label style={yshift=-9.8em}` as some trial-and-error estimate. I need to do this for various other diagrams and it might be a bit cumbersome to guess and set the `yshift` manually, is there a way to automatically place the text at the bottom of the dashed line?

[image: ex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\meter` command is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\meter}{O{}O{2em}O{1.5em}m}{%
\gate[#1,priority label=above,ps=meter,disable auto height][#2][#3]{#4}
}
```

Which means, that you cannot simply place the label below, because any such styling will be overridden by the `priority label` option. I am unsure why the package maintainer defined this in such a way. However, as you can see: a `\meter` is just a `\gate` with some additional styling. So, you can easily use this in your code. Also, I would suggest that you don't use `yshift` with some rule-of-thumb values to position the `\slice` labels, but instead change the `pos` value and the alignment anchor:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{a}
    & \gate[2, style={fill=blue!20, rounded corners}]{A} 
        \slice[style=blue, label style={pos=1, anchor=north}]{A1}
    & 
    &
    & \gate[3, priority label=below, ps=meter, disable auto height, 
        style={fill=red!25, rounded corners}]{X} \\
    \lstick{b}
    &
    & \gate[style={fill=green!25, rounded corners}]{S} 
    & \gate[2, style={fill=orange!20, rounded corners}]{B} 
        \slice[label style={pos=1, anchor=north}]{B1} 
    &\\
    \lstick{c}
    &
    & 
    & 
    &
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The style `pos=1, anchor=north` works great.